# How to print the running Selenium version from Java code

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Versionex
{

    @Test
    public void findversion()
    {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        Capabilities caps = ((ChromeDriver) driver).getCapabilities();
        String version = caps.getVersion();
        System.out.println("Running Selenium version: " + version);
        driver.quit();
    }


}
```

FAILED: findversion

java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:

The method getVersion() is undefined for the type Capabilities

Unresolved compilation problem:

Answer (score 0):

Try:
String version = caps.getBrowserVersion();